# Kaminari pagination slow with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, pagination, kaminari

I am using Kaminari to paginate two sets of data on a page in my app. One set of data has around 620 records and the other around 150. So not many compared to some.

However, the pagination partials are taking around 900ms to load for each. See: `21:46:38 rails.1 |   Rendered items/_paginator.erb (952.8ms)`

Apparently this is due to a `COUNT` that Kaminari is doing. More details here: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/545

I have looked around, even here on SO and found similar questions and loads of answers on how to speed up COUNT but nothing in relation to speeding it up in tandem with Kaminari.

Any ideas on how to do this?

My terminal output for this request:

```
22:46:31 rails.1 |    (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "coasters" WHERE "coasters"."superseded_at" IS NULL AND (material = 'steel')
22:46:31 rails.1 |    (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "coasters" WHERE "coasters"."superseded_at" IS NULL AND (material = 'wood')
22:46:31 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_breadcrumb_text.html.erb (9.6ms)
22:46:31 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_fact_bar.html.erb (0.3ms)
22:46:32 rails.1 |   ParkChain Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "park_chains".* FROM "park_chains"
22:46:32 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/parks/_filter_links.html.erb (11.5ms)
22:46:32 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/coasters/_filter_links.html.erb (3.2ms)
22:46:33 rails.1 |    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "parks"
22:46:33 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/parks/_park_paginator.erb (1029.5ms)
22:46:33 rails.1 |   Park Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "parks".* FROM "parks"  ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
22:46:33 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/parks/_park.html.erb (7.9ms)
22:46:33 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/parks/_park_grid.html.erb (175.6ms)
22:46:34 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/parks/_park_paginator.erb (961.1ms)
22:46:36 rails.1 |    (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "coasters"."id") FROM "coasters" LEFT OUTER JOIN "parks" ON "parks"."id" = "coasters"."park_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cycles" ON "cycles"."coaster_id" = "coasters"."id" WHERE "coasters"."superseded_at" IS NULL
22:46:36 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/coasters/_coaster_paginator.erb (1104.5ms)
22:46:36 rails.1 |   SQL (2.6ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "coasters"."id", parks.name AS alias_0, coasters.name AS alias_1 FROM "coasters" LEFT OUTER JOIN "parks" ON "parks"."id" = "coasters"."park_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cycles" ON "cycles"."coaster_id" = "coasters"."id" WHERE "coasters"."superseded_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY parks.name ASC, coasters.name ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
22:46:36 rails.1 |   SQL (16.8ms)  SELECT "coasters"."id" AS t0_r0, "coasters"."name" AS t0_r1, "coasters"."inversions" AS t0_r2, "coasters"."material" AS t0_r3, "coasters"."notes" AS t0_r4, "coasters"."lat" AS t0_r5, "coasters"."lng" AS t0_r6, "coasters"."manufacturer_id" AS t0_r7, "coasters"."park_id" AS t0_r8, "coasters"."created_at" AS t0_r9, "coasters"."updated_at" AS t0_r10, "coasters"."slug" AS t0_r11, "coasters"."covering" AS t0_r12, "coasters"."style" AS t0_r13, "coasters"."model" AS t0_r14, "coasters"."layout" AS t0_r15, "coasters"."order_ridden" AS t0_r16, "coasters"."dates_ridden" AS t0_r17, "coasters"."on_ride_photo" AS t0_r18, "coasters"."powered" AS t0_r19, "coasters"."length" AS t0_r20, "coasters"."height" AS t0_r21, "coasters"."speed" AS t0_r22, "coasters"."coaster_sort" AS t0_r23, "coasters"."is_milestone" AS t0_r24, "coasters"."version_number" AS t0_r25, "coasters"."version_reason" AS t0_r26, "coasters"."version_ridden_after" AS t0_r27, "coasters"."position" AS t0_r28, "coasters"."relocated" AS t0_r29, "coasters"."renamed" AS t0_r30, "coasters"."rethemed" AS t0_r31, "coasters"."steel_10" AS t0_r32, "coasters"."wood_10" AS t0_r33, "coasters"."original_version_id" AS t0_r34, "coasters"."superseded_at" AS t0_r35, "parks"."id" AS t1_r0, "parks"."name" AS t1_r1, "parks"."location_1" AS t1_r2, "parks"."location_2" AS t1_r3, "parks"."location_3" AS t1_r4, "parks"."lat" AS t1_r5, "parks"."lng" AS t1_r6, "parks"."created_at" AS t1_r7, "parks"."updated_at" AS t1_r8, "parks"."location_4" AS t1_r9, "parks"."country" AS t1_r10, "parks"."park_chain_id" AS t1_r11, "parks"."notes" AS t1_r12, "parks"."visit_count" AS t1_r13, "parks"."dates_visited" AS t1_r14, "parks"."slug" AS t1_r15, "parks"."order_visited" AS t1_r16, "parks"."logo" AS t1_r17, "cycles"."id" AS t2_r0, "cycles"."coaster_id" AS t2_r1, "cycles"."notes" AS t2_r2, "cycles"."date" AS t2_r3, "cycles"."created_at" AS t2_r4, "cycles"."updated_at" AS t2_r5 FROM "coasters" LEFT OUTER JOIN "parks" ON "parks"."id" = "coasters"."park_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cycles" ON "cycles"."coaster_id" = "coasters"."id" WHERE "coasters"."superseded_at" IS NULL AND "coasters"."id" IN (21926, 22414, 21927, 21939, 21963, 21964, 21962, 21965, 21800, 21790, 21791, 21793, 21794, 21795, 22378, 21845, 21792, 21842, 21941, 22179, 22144, 22145, 22065, 22196, 22188)  ORDER BY parks.name ASC, coasters.name ASC
22:46:36 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/coasters/_coaster.html.erb (273.5ms)
22:46:36 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/coasters/_coaster_grid.html.erb (576.9ms)
22:46:37 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/coasters/_coaster_paginator.erb (968.7ms)
22:46:37 rails.1 |   Rendered theme_parks/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6285.8ms)
22:46:38 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_banner_slideshow.html.erb (0.1ms)
22:46:38 rails.1 |   Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
22:46:38 rails.1 | Completed 200 OK in 7547ms (Views: 7216.3ms | ActiveRecord: 33.3ms)
```

UPDATE: [image]

Comment: If that single SQL call is taking almost 1 second to run there is something misconfigured with your database. I have a table with 570K rows and it takes 333ms.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom ok. How would I find what is causing the slowdown on the DB end and to reconfigure it to be faster as I realise my number of records is nowhere near the amount others like yourself have.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom If I just run a standard COUNT query, it's really fast but when it's a part of Kaminari, then it's slow and the pagination render takes between 900 - 1000ms. So it's Kaminari but I can't find a solution to fix it.

Comment: Make sure you run the same query the kaminari runs - is there a chance you have some filters in place?  You should be able to see the offending query in the logs.

Comment: You are not giving us much details here. What exactly makes you think it is the count method that is slow? have you measured it? Or it it just because it is the problem for others?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Not quite sure what I should be looking for in the output but I have posted above in my OP.

Comment: @Meier Yes, I am assuming based on that GitHub issue. I am most likely incorrect though. I have posted my terminal output above.

Comment: so it looks like there is a problem in coaster_paginator.erb, but _coaster.html.erb and _coaster_grid.html.erb are also rather slow.

Comment: `Views: 7216.3ms | ActiveRecord: 33.3ms`: your database appears to have nothing to do with it, actual interaction with the database is less than 0.5% of the total render time. There is something else slowing down the process. You may need a profiler to find it.

Comment: Note that you can copy Kaminari's views into your app and step through them with a tool like `pry-byebug` to identify the misbehaving line (the delay is well noticeable for human eye).

Comment: @D-side I have added rack-mini-profiler's output to my OP. I ahve inlined a few of my nested rails partials in my view file which helped a tiny bit but not much. Everything is pointing to Kaminari and the paginate calls I am making but I have no idea how to procede from here.

Comment: I have no other explaination other than you're paginating a quite complex query. `SQL (16.8ms)  SELECT "coasters"."id" AS t0_r0 ...` in particular looks suspicious. I've seen queries like these before, but I have no idea what can cause them to get built this way.

Answer (score 0):

I did some analysis. I have tested the rendering speed on PostgreSQL and MySQL is the same. After I optimised the query to 300ms, rendering was 2500-3500ms. There are two things that made my rendering much faster.

1. I commented out `gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'`, rendering decreased to 1000ms but it was ugly. If I copy erb files from that gem to my `app/views/kaminari` folder, I also get 1000ms and it looks good. That was a surprise.
2. I tried `.page(params[:page]).without_count` and rendering decreased to 150ms. It is different type of pagination, so I have to think if it is suitable for my app.

BTW it was faster on Rails 4.2, now I am upgrading to 5.2 and have this problem.